# Add notification for events on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: headless, script

I am running my raspberry PI in a head-less fashion and it is therefore very valuable to be notified of certain events.

So I should be able to do something like the following:

```
/usr/bin/log_message "Something just happened"
```

I then want to be notified about this on my work station using growl or slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Slack Script

1. Configure a new Incoming Webhook through slack https://YOURTEAM.slack.com/services/new
2. You'll get a custom URL that will be used later on. So make sure to replace it with any occurences of the URL template:

   ```
   https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   ```
3. Create a binary and add the contents below

   ```
   touch /usr/bin/slack
   chmod +x /usr/bin/slack
   nano /usr/bin/slack
   ```
4. The Script:

   ```
       #!/bin/bash

       MESSAGE=$1
       USERNAME="Raspi"
       CHANNEL="#general"
       ICON=":computer:"
       curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"$CHANNEL\", \"text\": \"$MESSAGE\", \"username\": \"$USERNAME\", \"icon_emoji\": \"$ICON\"}" -k $SLACK_URL
   ```
5. Add the following line to `~/.profile`. This ensures that the `slack` command can be used inside a terminal:

   ```
   export SLACK_URL=https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   ```

### Example

Get notified when Raspberry PI starts up:

```
touch /etc/init.d/startup_notification.sh
chmod +x /etc/init.d/startup_notification.sh
update-rc.d startup_notification.sh defaults
nano /etc/init.d/startup_notification.sh
```

The script `startup_notification.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

export SLACK_URL=export SLACK_URL=https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
/usr/bin/slack "The raspberry PI has started up \n> $(uname -a)\n$(ifconfig)" &
```

This gives me a nice notification along with the network details: